# What type of wood siding should I use for a shed? 

Tags: siding, shed, lumber

What kinds of inexpensive wood siding, suitable for a shed, are commonly available in the U.S.?  I checked Lowe's and Home Depot, but all they had was a single type of barn-style shiplap.  I had expected more of a selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T-111 is pretty much the standard for that kind of stuff.  What kind of a look are you going for?  You could always sheath it with OSB and put anything you want on top of that (vinyl, clapboard, etc.)

Comment: T1-11 is plywood with grooves?

Comment: @Vebjorn - yes, it's the lapped plywood with vertical grooves.  Typically it's made of OSB and "stamped" on the outside with the grooves and a "natural wood" like pattern (and often pre-primed as well)